# how to modify objects from a list and return them in a new list

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, deep-copy

So I am trying to add a tag to those beautiful soup tags.
However with this code only last tag of the list will keep the added tag. Previous tags will have it during iteration and then will lose it. Changes are not persistent.

```
import bs4


def add_tag(souplist, p):
    newlist = []
    for div in souplist:
        div.append(p)  # beautiful soup append
        newlist.append(div)  # list append
    return newlist
```

Input

```
soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div>a</div></body></html>').find('div')
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div>b</div></body></html>').find('div')
soup3 = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div>c</div></body></html>').find('div')

souplist = [soup1, soup2, soup3]
p = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p>foo</p>').find('p')

refinedlist = add_tag(souplist, p)
```

Output

I am expecting this output for refinedlist:

```
>>> [<div>a<p>foo</p></div>, <div>b<p>foo</p></div>, <div>c<p>foo</p></div>]
```

but I get this instead

```
>>> [<div>a</div>, <div>b</div>, <div>c<p>foo</p></div>]
```

Note: if a do

```
 newlist.append(deepcopy(div))  # list append
```

it works but for big enough objects it triggers "maximum recursion limit exceeded...." exception which could be avoided by setting such parameter to a (much) higher value. however when you see yourself modifying sys parameters and using deepcopy just to accomplish a simple operation, I guess probably something is being done wrong.

So how do you usually get a list of object, modify them, and return a list with the modified objects? there must be an easier way for such common task

Comment: what do you mean? I think I do only one loop already, right?

Comment: sure! I added it in the question

Comment: it don't think it will, but it's not the problem cause I can always use find() and get it. the problem is that it does not persist for all 3 elements of the list. only last one. I need it on all three

Comment: I'd guess that adding a BeautifulSoup element to another element removes it from wherever else it had been added. That is, your `p` value can only be contained by one of the `soupN` divs at a time.

Comment: @Danny, I added an answer, you need to create a new `p` object each time

Answer (score 0):

```
final = []
souplist = [soup1, soup2, soup3]
for s in souplist:
   p = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p>foo</p>').find('p')
   s.append(p)
   final.append(s)
print(final)
[<div>a<p>foo</p></div>, <div>b<p>foo</p></div>, <div>c<p>foo</p></div>]
```

You need to create a new `p = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p>foo</p>').find('p')` object for each append

```
def add_tag(souplist, p):
    newlist = []
    for div in souplist:
        p = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<p>foo</p>').find('p')
        div.append(p)  # beautiful soup append
        newlist.append(div)  # list append
    return newlist
```

Comment: @Danny, what does that mean? Why can you not just create a new instance each time?

Comment: I will receive p as a parameter of the function. So, I don't know what it looks like till it gets passed.

Comment: where is it coming from?

Comment: p is typically coming from another function. but I am trying to write a generic function. i kept this example simple for clarity and not to copy and paste too much code... but in general I won't be setting up the input (so I cannot know in advance that p has to be'<p>foo</p>' till i read it..) I can only write a function good enough to handle any tag

Comment: I am beginning to think there is a fundamental flaw in your design, you should be creating new objects, what does the function do exactly?

Comment: it should add a link (bs4 tag) to a given resultset (a list of bs4 elements) in case there is none, and then will put everything in a new list and pass it back to another function that needs the link and the bs4 elements one by one. this is just the part where given a list of bs4 elements and a tag, I add the tag to all elements and return the new list that will contain them. I already handle everything else.

Comment: can you not call the function in the loop, or is it an expensive func? I still think your main problem is your design

Comment: I mean I am implementing this to handle these kind of corner cases where some bs4 elements are lacking a link that usually should have been there. the function will be called for each of the bs4 elements, (after I execute this code) by the base class and ideally will receive all the bs4 elements with the link I injected

Comment: but I see a more general problem here, I am executing 3 lines of code over a list of objects, and unless I use deepcopy() it miss-behaves. but as i said I don't love the idea of deepcopy cause it raises excpetions...